# Is minimum interval hitting problem NP-HARD?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard, constraint-satisfaction, intervals

Consider this problem:

We want to mark some integer numbers such that we mark the minimum number of the numbers and satisfy some constraints. Each constraint wants that at least $k$ numbers in interval $[i,j]$ should be marked such that $i \leq j$ and $k \leq j-i+1$. Is this problem NP-HARD? If yes, please prove it. If no, please provide a polynomial time algorithm for it. If you know any papers about it, please inform me.

Answer (score 1):

It should be solvable in Polynomial time (in the number of constraints + $\max j$) by MaxFlow algorithms. Consider first [this link explaining how you can determine the minimum amount of flow on a network with edge demands](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/flow_with_demands.html). Then build the following network:

Start with a source node $s$, then create a set $J$ of  $\max j$ nodes that $s$ points to with edges of capacity $1$ and no demand. Next, create a set $C$ with $\# \text{constraints}$ nodes and for every constraint node in $C$ create an edge of capacity $1$ and demand $0$ from every node in $J$ that's in the range of the constraint toward the constraint node. Then, create a target node $t$ and connect each constraint node in $C$ with an edge of infinite capacity but demand $k$.

It should be clear by construction that the minimal amount of flow satisfying all capacity and demands is the answer to your problem.